# Chrome extension - persistent popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Whenever an extension's popup is closed, its entire context is destroyed.

Given that I've got a React tree there, I don't want it to unmount  and lose its state whenever the user closes the popup.

Is it possible to make the popup's context persistent?

Comment: Store the state in chrome.storage.local or use messaging to store it in the background script. There should be components around for both, IIRC.